# ¿Como insertar varios registros a una tabla con 2 parametros de un SP? SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql, sql-server-2016

para mi pregunta realmente no tengo idea si se puede realizar o no y quiero consultarlo con ustedes y llegar a una posible solucion, la cuestion aqui es que necesito realizar un procedimiento almacenado el cual me inserte varios registros con solo dos parametros es decir que el usuario en un primer parametro ingrese los codigos de los productos a insertar y en el segundo parametro el codigo al que pertenece de la siguiente forma:

> exec ejemploSP @cod_prod = '10002,10003,10004', @codigo =
> 'MX-MN209,MX-PR341,MX-SN809,ARG-21'

Lo anterior es solo un ejemplo de como quisiera que recibiera los parametros, y con estos parametros me gustaria insertar los datos a una tabla de la siguiente manera:

```
cod_prod      codigo

10002         MX-MN209
10002         MX-PR341
10002         MX-SN809
10002         ARG-21
10003         MX-MN209
10003         MX-PR341
10003         MX-SN809
10003         ARG-21
10004         MX-MN209
10004         MX-PR341
10004         MX-SN809
10004         ARG-21
```

¿Se podria insertar de esta manera los datos recibidos con los parametros que les mencione?
y si es asi, como lo podria realizar? ya que solo tengo idea de como hacerlo de esta manera pero no los estaria insertando como quiero sino que solo los insertaria en un registro:

```
INSERT INTO tabla (columna1, columna2, ...) 

VALUES (valor1, valor2, ...), 
(valor1, valor2, ...), 
...
(valor1n, valor2n, ...);
```

Gracias por su ayuda!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Antes que nada, dejame decirte que no es la forma más adecuada de realizar un `insert`, esto requiere un procesamiento previo que suele ser más seguro si se  resuelve desde la aplicación que desde el servidor, hablo de las combinaciones. De todas formas es posible hacerlo, pero tienes dos cuestiones a resolver:

1. El `split` de los dos parámetros para transformar cada valor en una nueva fila
2. El producto cartesiano para generar todas las combinaciones.

El punto 2 es fácil de resolver mediante el join `CROSS APPLY`, y para el punto 1 hay muchas soluciones posibles, mi favorita es transformar cada valor en un item en formato XML para luego trabajarlo como tal:

```
DECLARE @cod_prod  VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @codigo    VARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT  @cod_prod  = '10002,10003,10004', 
        @codigo    = 'MX-MN209,MX-PR341,MX-SN809,ARG-21'

SELECT a.cod_prod,
       b.codigo
       FROM (
            SELECT Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS 'cod_prod'
                    FROM  (SELECT CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(STRING, ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data  
                                  FROM  (SELECT @cod_prod AS 'STRING') T
                        ) AS A 
                        CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)
        ) a
        CROSS APPLY (
            SELECT Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS 'codigo'
                   FROM  (SELECT CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(STRING, ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data  
                                 FROM  (SELECT @codigo AS 'STRING') T
                        ) AS A 
                        CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)
        ) b

+-------+----------+
| 10002 | MX-MN209 |
+-------+----------+
| 10002 | MX-PR341 |
+-------+----------+
| 10002 | MX-SN809 |
+-------+----------+
| 10002 | ARG-21   |
+-------+----------+
| 10003 | MX-MN209 |
+-------+----------+
| 10003 | MX-PR341 |
+-------+----------+
| 10003 | MX-SN809 |
+-------+----------+
| 10003 | ARG-21   |
+-------+----------+
| 10004 | MX-MN209 |
+-------+----------+
| 10004 | MX-PR341 |
+-------+----------+
| 10004 | MX-SN809 |
+-------+----------+
| 10004 | ARG-21   |
+-------+----------+
```

Con los valores generados solo restaría agregar el `INSERT`.

Comment: Realmente no se como funciona utilizar XML, pero funciono de la manera que estaba buscando, thanks!

Comment: amigo, hay una manera para validar si existe el registro antes de insertar los datos?

Comment: Si, podrías combinar esta consulta con un `LEFT JOIN` a la tabla dónde vaya a insertar, y filtrar solo las filas dónde no existas filas del lado del `LEFT`

Answer (score 2):

Una opción simple es utilizar "algo" para dividir por el separador que determina que un código es un código. En el caso del ejemplo la ','.

Para poder dividir hay muchas funciones disponibles en la web. Aunque Sql Server en la versión que utilizas incorpora split_String, esta no te devuelve un número de fila, y no puede asegurar el ordenamiento de las filas devueltas por la posición.
Yo te voy a poner una función, aunque hay muchas otras que lo hacen, y será cuestión tuya escoger la que mejor se adapte a lo que necesites.

**Escenario**.

```
Create table dbo.datosEjemplo
(
    cod_prod varchar(100),
    codigo varchar(100)
);
```

**Función de apoyo para split**

[Delimitted split 8k de Jeff Moden](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/tally-oh-an-improved-sql-8k-%E2%80%9Ccsv-splitter%E2%80%9D-function)

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[DelimitedSplit8K]
--===== Define I/O parameters
        (@pString VARCHAR(8000), @pDelimiter CHAR(1))
--WARNING!!! DO NOT USE MAX DATA-TYPES HERE!  IT WILL KILL PERFORMANCE!
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
 RETURN
--===== "Inline" CTE Driven "Tally Table" produces values from 1 up to 10,000...
     -- enough to cover VARCHAR(8000)
  WITH E1(N) AS (
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
                ),                          --10E+1 or 10 rows
       E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
       E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
 cteTally(N) AS (--==== This provides the "base" CTE and limits the number of rows right up front
                     -- for both a performance gain and prevention of accidental "overruns"
                 SELECT TOP (ISNULL(DATALENGTH(@pString),0)) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
                ),
cteStart(N1) AS (--==== This returns N+1 (starting position of each "element" just once for each delimiter)
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT t.N+1 FROM cteTally t WHERE SUBSTRING(@pString,t.N,1) = @pDelimiter
                ),
cteLen(N1,L1) AS(--==== Return start and length (for use in substring)
                 SELECT s.N1,
                        ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@pDelimiter,@pString,s.N1),0)-s.N1,8000)
                   FROM cteStart s
                )
--===== Do the actual split. The ISNULL/NULLIF combo handles the length for the final element when no delimiter is found.
 SELECT ItemNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY l.N1),
        Item       = SUBSTRING(@pString, l.N1, l.L1)
   FROM cteLen l
;
```

Ejecutas el script y la consumes, no es necesario que la entiendas **de momento**.

***Procedure***

```
Create or alter procedure dbo.ejemploSp
(
    @cod_prod varchar(1000),
    @codigo varchar(1000)
)
As
Begin
    
    Insert into dbo.datosEjemplo(cod_prod, codigo)
    Select fn1.item, fn2.Item
    from dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(@cod_prod,',') fn1
        cross apply 
        dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(@codigo,',') fn2
    where fn1.ItemNumber = fn2.ItemNumber

End
```

Esto si es necesario que lo entiendas.

Como ejemplo

```
Declare @cod_prod varchar(1000) = '10002,10003,10004';
Declare @codigo varchar(1000) = 'MX-MN209,MX-PR341,MX-SN809,ARG-21';

Select *
    from dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(@cod_prod,',') fn1
        cross apply 
        dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(@codigo,',') fn2
    where fn1.ItemNumber = fn2.ItemNumber;
```

[image: Res]

Esto que hace. Parte cada uno de los valores de las variables por el separador en filas. Cada función devuelve un itemNumber y un Item, respetando la posición. Por tanto si las dos funciones devuelven las filas divididas e igualas la posición, tienes la sentencia de inserción.

```
exec ejemploSP @cod_prod = '10002,10003,10004', @codigo = 'MX-MN209,MX-PR341,MX-SN809,ARG-21';
```

Y la ejecución ha hecho:

[image: Result]

Comment: **queja**: _split_ es un verbo en inglés que no se puede conjugar en español. El verbo _splitear_ no existe. Puedes usar verbos en español como dividir, separar, etc. Sé que es difícil, me enfrento a esas dificultades todos los días, pero creo que no debemos abandonar el idioma. Por aquí también les encanta usar el verbo _crash_ como si existiera en español. Justo leí una pregunta donde un código _crashea_. Mi maestra de 3o. primaria daría vueltas en su tumba.

Comment: @jachguate Tienes razón. Y así lo he modificado. Viva el español.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes preparar un CTE recursivo para convertir los valores recibidos como lista separada por comas en filas. En cada iteración vas extrayendo uno de los valores y dejando la cadena ya sin este valor, hasta que se termine la cadena.

Por ejemplo:

```
declare @cod_prod varchar(max) = '10002,10003,10004';

with 
vcod_prod(cod_prod, string) AS (
select   left(@cod_prod, charindex(',', @cod_prod + ',') - 1)
       , stuff(@cod_prod, 1, charindex(',', @cod_prod + ','), '')
union all
select   left(String, charindex(',', String + ',') - 1)
       , stuff(String, 1, charindex(',', String + ','), '')
  from vcod_prod
 where string > ''
)
select cod_prod
  from vcod_prod;
```

devuelve:

```
cod_prod
--------
10002
10003
10004
```

Una vez tienes los dos CTE's, digamos `vcod_prod` y `vcodigo`, lo que haría falta es obtener el producto cartesiano de ellos, que lo puedes hacer con un `cross join`

Por ejemplo:

```
with
vcod_prod as (
  -- el query recursivo
)
, 
vcodigo as (
  -- el query recursivo
)
select vcod_prod.cod_prod, vcodigo.codigo
  from vcod_prod
       cross join vcodigo;
```

Nos devuelve:

```
cod_prod codigo
-------- --------
10002    MX-MN209
10003    MX-MN209
10004    MX-MN209
10002    MX-PR341
10003    MX-PR341
10004    MX-PR341
10002    MX-SN809
10003    MX-SN809
10004    MX-SN809
10002    ARG-21
10003    ARG-21
10004    ARG-21

(12 rows affected)
```

Lo siguiente sería preparar un insert usando los datos de ese select:

```
with
vcod_prod as (
  -- el query recursivo
)
, 
vcodigo as (
  -- el query recursivo
)
insert into miTabla(cod_prod, codigo)
select vcod_prod.cod_prod, vcodigo.codigo
  from vcod_prod
       cross join vcodigo;
```