# ¿Como insertar solo registros que no existen en inserción masiva?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Se que hay varias respuestas a lo que pregunté, pero lo que yo busco es un tanto diferente y no he encontrado una respuesta. Hace poco hice la pregunta:
[¿Como insertar varios registros a una tabla con 2 parametros de un SP?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/595557/como-insertar-varios-registros-a-una-tabla-con-2-parametros-de-un-sp-sql-serve/595565#595565),
y gracias a su ayuda logré resolver mi duda, pero ahora me gustaría validar si existen los registros en la tabla antes de insertar los resultados; este es el query que me recomendaron y estoy usando:

```
DECLARE @cod_prod  VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @codigo    VARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT  @cod_prod  = '10002,10003,10004', 
        @codigo    = 'MX-MN209,MX-PR341,MX-SN809,ARG-21'

INSERT INTO Temp_Rep065(cod_prod, codigo)
SELECT a.cod_prod,
       b.codigo
       FROM (
            SELECT Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS 'cod_prod'
                    FROM  (SELECT CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(STRING, ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data  
                                  FROM  (SELECT @cod_prod AS 'STRING') T
                        ) AS A 
                        CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)
        ) a
        CROSS APPLY (
            SELECT Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS 'codigo'
                   FROM  (SELECT CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(STRING, ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data  
                                 FROM  (SELECT @codigo AS 'STRING') T
                        ) AS A 
                        CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)
        ) b

+-------+----------+
| 10002 | MX-MN209 |
+-------+----------+
| 10002 | MX-PR341 |
+-------+----------+
| 10002 | MX-SN809 |
+-------+----------+
| 10002 | ARG-21   |
+-------+----------+
| 10003 | MX-MN209 |
+-------+----------+
| 10003 | MX-PR341 |
+-------+----------+
| 10003 | MX-SN809 |
+-------+----------+
| 10003 | ARG-21   |
+-------+----------+
| 10004 | MX-MN209 |
+-------+----------+
| 10004 | MX-PR341 |
+-------+----------+
| 10004 | MX-SN809 |
+-------+----------+
| 10004 | ARG-21   |
+-------+----------+
```

Y pues, como les comenté, este query me sirvió de mucha ayuda, pero quise validar si existía el registro en la tabla, pero me encontré con el problema que para validar necesito hacer algo como lo siguiente:

```
if exists (select * from Temp_Rep065 where cod_prod = @cod_prod and
  codigo = @codigo)
```

Pero dado que los parámetros que recibe estan todos en una variable, no sé como puedo validarlos uno por uno, de acuerdo a los valores recibidos. ¿Alguien tiene una idea de como hacerlo?

¡Gracias por su ayuda nuevamente!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agrega un `LEFT JOIN` a la tabla dónde piensas insertar las filas y filtras aquellas que ya existan:

```
        LEFT JOIN Temp_Rep065 t
             ON t.cod_prod = a.codprod
             AND t.codigo = b.codigo
        WHERE t.cod_prod IS NULL
```

Las filas que ya existan en la tabla tendrán un `t.cod_prod` distinto de `NULL` por lo que si buscas por `NULL` obtenemos los casos que no existan. Ten en cuenta que esto no evita que insertes dos filas iguales si ya las tienes en las cadenas que dividimos en filas, solo evitamos insertar si los valores ya existen en la tabla.

Consulta:

```
SELECT a.cod_prod,
       b.codigo
       FROM (
            SELECT Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS 'cod_prod'
                    FROM  (SELECT CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(STRING, ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data  
                                  FROM  (SELECT @cod_prod AS 'STRING') T
                        ) AS A 
                        CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)
        ) a
        CROSS APPLY (
            SELECT Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS 'codigo'
                   FROM  (SELECT CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(STRING, ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data  
                                 FROM  (SELECT @codigo AS 'STRING') T
                        ) AS A 
                        CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)
        ) b
        LEFT JOIN Temp_Rep065 t
             ON t.cod_prod = a.codprod
             AND t.codigo = b.codigo
        WHERE t.cod_prod IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

Utiliza la cláusula [`except`](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-except-and-intersect-transact-sql), que fue creada exactamente para eso. Por tanto, no solo el resultado es el esperado sino que, al leer la consulta, queda muy claro de una primera vista cuál es la intención de la misma.

En operaciones de conjuntos, `except` es el equivalente a una resta de conjuntos, que te devuelve como resultado los elementos de un conjunto que no están en otro.

Su sintaxis básica es:

```
primera cláusula select 
except
segunda cláusula select
```

Ambas consultas deben devolver la misma cantidad de campos.

A la consulta con la que obtienes los datos para insertar solo habría que añadirle:

```
except
select cod_prod, codigo from Temp_Rep065
```

Asegúrate de tener un índice por ambos campos (Ya que no se repiten, sería ideal si fuesen la llave primaria o, por lo menos, un índice único sobre ellos)

Ya completa la sentencia, quedaría así:

```
INSERT INTO Temp_Rep065(cod_prod, codigo)
SELECT a.cod_prod,
       b.codigo
       FROM (
            SELECT Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS 'cod_prod'
                    FROM  (SELECT CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(STRING, ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data  
                                  FROM  (SELECT @cod_prod AS 'STRING') T
                        ) AS A 
                        CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)
        ) a
        CROSS APPLY (
            SELECT Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS 'codigo'
                   FROM  (SELECT CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(STRING, ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data  
                                 FROM  (SELECT @codigo AS 'STRING') T
                        ) AS A 
                        CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)
        ) b
except
select cod_prod, codigo
  from Temp_Rep065
```

Answer (score 1):

Una opción más, es utilizar `NOT EXISTS`. Esta opción tiene mejor rendimiento que usar `LEFT JOIN` y más versatilidad que `EXCEPT` porque solo compara un conjunto de columnas y no toda la fila.

También dejo una simplificación de tu código juntando ambas operaciones para dividir las cadenas.

```
DECLARE @cod_prod  VARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @codigo    VARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT  @cod_prod  = '10002,10003,10004', 
        @codigo    = 'MX-MN209,MX-PR341,MX-SN809,ARG-21';

WITH cteCodigos AS(
    SELECT SplitCp.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS 'cod_prod',
           SplitCo.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS 'codigo'
    FROM  (SELECT CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(@cod_prod, ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Cod_Prods,
                  CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(@codigo  , ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Codigos) AS A 
    CROSS APPLY Cod_Prods.nodes ('/M') AS SplitCp(a)
    CROSS APPLY Codigos.nodes ('/M') AS SplitCo(a)
)
INSERT INTO Temp_Rep065(cod_prod, codigo)
SELECT co.cod_prod,
       co.codigo
FROM cteCodigos co
WHERE NOT EXISTS( SELECT *
                  FROM Temp_Rep065 tr
                  WHERE tr.cod_prod = co.cod_prod
                  AND   tr.codigo   = co.codigo);
```

En mi caso, uso un CTE para factorizar el código, pero realmente se puede hacer de forma directa.

```
INSERT INTO Temp_Rep065(cod_prod, codigo)
SELECT co.cod_prod,
       co.codigo
FROM (
    SELECT SplitCp.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS 'cod_prod',
           SplitCo.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS 'codigo'
    FROM  (SELECT CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(@cod_prod, ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Cod_Prods,
                  CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(@codigo  , ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Codigos) AS A 
    CROSS APPLY Cod_Prods.nodes ('/M') AS SplitCp(a)
    CROSS APPLY Codigos.nodes ('/M') AS SplitCo(a)) co
WHERE NOT EXISTS( SELECT *
                  FROM Temp_Rep065 tr
                  WHERE tr.cod_prod = co.cod_prod
                  AND   tr.codigo   = co.codigo);
```