# ¿Como insertar/actualizar registros en inserción masiva? SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Eh tenido algunos problemas al querer actualizar registros que ya existen con el query el cual me ayudaron a realizar: [¿Como insertar solo registros que no existen en inserción masiva?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/595816/como-insertar-solo-registros-que-no-existen-en-inserci%C3%B3n-masiva) puesto que en esa pregunta queria saber como validar que no existieran para proceder a insertar los registros, bueno ahora tengo que validar si existe un registro con los mismos valores de las variables @cod_prod y @codigo, para despues si existe solo modificar el valor de la columna "calif" y en caso de que no exista el registro, ahora sí insertar el registro. El problema es que no he podido encontrar una manera de como hacerlo, ¿Hay una manera de realizar esto con este query? Realmente les agradeceria mucho su ayuda!

Gracias por sus respuestas :)

Este es el query que me ayuda a seleccionar los registros que no existen para poder insertarlos:

```
DECLARE @cod_prod  VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @codigo    VARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT  @cod_prod  = '10002,10003,10004', 
        @codigo    = 'MX-MN209,MX-PR341,MX-SN809,ARG-21'

INSERT INTO Temp_Rep065(cod_prod,codigo,calif)
SELECT a.cod_prod,
       b.codigo,
       case when(b.codigo != '')
         then 'N/A'      
       end as 'calif'
       FROM (
            SELECT Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS 'cod_prod'
                    FROM  (SELECT CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(STRING, ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data  
                                  FROM  (SELECT @cod_prod AS 'STRING') T
                        ) AS A 
                        CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)
        ) a
        CROSS APPLY (
            SELECT Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS 'codigo'
                   FROM  (SELECT CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(STRING, ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data  
                                 FROM  (SELECT @codigo AS 'STRING') T
                        ) AS A 
                        CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)
        ) b
        LEFT JOIN Temp_Rep065 t
             ON t.cod_prod = a.codprod
             AND t.codigo = b.codigo
        WHERE t.cod_prod IS NULL
```

Comment: Saludos. En caso sea solo `UPDATE` o `INSERT` a realizar (no necesites obtener para usar el nuevo ID o el existente para una operación posterior) usa `MERGE` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16 en caso que a futuro requeriras usar el ID (nuevo o existentes) usa `WHILE` y variables que requieras.

Comment: Según la lógica que se muestra ¿La columna calif siempre será `N/A`?

Comment: @LuisCazares Así es, ya sea para el caso de actualizar o insertar siempre debera tener N/A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que acostumbro hacer es primero actualizar los datos y luego insertar los faltantes. Podría usar `MERGE` y seguramente alguien lo sugerirá, pero me he encontrado con problemas de rendimiento aleatorios. En este caso, como hay que generar el conjunto de datos, lo guardo primero en una tabla temporal.

```
DECLARE @cod_prod  VARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @codigo    VARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT  @cod_prod  = '10002,10003,10004', 
        @codigo    = 'MX-MN209,MX-PR341,MX-SN809,ARG-21';

SELECT SplitCp.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS 'cod_prod',
       SplitCo.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS 'codigo'
INTO #Codigos
FROM  (SELECT CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(@cod_prod, ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Cod_Prods,
              CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(@codigo  , ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Codigos) AS A 
CROSS APPLY Cod_Prods.nodes ('/M') AS SplitCp(a)
CROSS APPLY Codigos.nodes ('/M') AS SplitCo(a)

UPDATE Temp_Rep065 
SET calif = 'N/A'
FROM Temp_Rep065 tr
JOIN #Codigos    co ON tr.cod_prod = co.cod_prod
                   AND tr.codigo   = co.codigo

INSERT INTO Temp_Rep065(cod_prod, codigo, calif)
SELECT co.cod_prod,
       co.codigo,
       'N/A'
FROM #Codigos co
WHERE NOT EXISTS( SELECT *
                  FROM Temp_Rep065 tr
                  WHERE tr.cod_prod = co.cod_prod
                  AND   tr.codigo   = co.codigo);

DROP TABLE #Codigos;
```

Comment: Una pregunta, me sale este error; There is already an object named '#Codigos' in the database. Se que es debido a que existe una tabla temporal con el mismo nombre pero el problema es que solo ejecuto la parte de tu codigo, sabes a que se debe?

Comment: Es porque ejecutaste la consulta más de una vez. Puedes destruir la tabla temporal al final del código. Voy a agregar eso a la respuesta.